# make mongodb insert() to ONLY insert data of object

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I've been trying out mongodb for a few days but I have a problem.
It was kind of diccicult for me to explain the problem in a short title though.

So my mongodb Collection creates an autoindex which I want it to create.
But when I insert a json like this:

```
var body // contains JSON data
collection.insert({
  body
});
```

The Object in my Collection looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59621dfb13eecc8a083d3951"),
    "body" : {
        "name" : "leaf",
        "type" : 2
        }
}
```

What I am aiming for though is for it to look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59621dfb13eecc8a083d3951"),
    "name" : "leaf",
    "type" : 2
}
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just insert `body` not object that contains `body`

```
collection.insert(body);
```